# Ctrl+A does not select all in URL bar in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Selecting all text in URL by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work anymore.
Now it brings the cursor to the front.

Comment: Is it only in the URL bar that this happens, or elsewhere on the computer too (e.g. in Gedit, LibreOffice, etc.)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following (not guaranteed to cover your problem but it's a possibility):

Open your Dash and type in "Tweak" to get to the Tweak Tool (Note that this is not the same as "Ubuntu Tweak") - alternatively, in a console type `gnome-tweak-tool` (if it is not currently installed, type `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` to install it)

Go to the *Keyboard & Mouse > Emacs input* (formerly *Theme section > Gtk+ Keybinding Theme*). If this is set to "Emacs", then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will essentially act as if it were the <kbd>Home</kbd> key. If this is the case, change the option to "Default" to restore the usual settings.

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, in Firefox and Google Chrome you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select the entire title bar.

Comment: You are the boss. That tweak worked (Y) :D

Comment: There is no `Theme section` in Ubuntu 18.04, any idea?

Comment: On terminal: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> usually goes to the front of the string in the CLI. You should check the Keyboard shortcuts by clicking the gear icon in the top right of your screen:

[image: Gear icon]

and then clicking:  <kbd>System Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Keyboard</kbd>

**Note:** On my PC, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> has the normal behaviour!

Comment: It was working normally but suddenly it stopped working.
Can not find select all shortcut at Keyboard settings.

Comment: @snoop: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/324864/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix it try using F6 ;)

Comment: a work around, but not a solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no Theme section in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.

This works on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

1. Open the dash and type "Tweaks" and open it.
2. Select Keyboard & Mouse
3. Disable Emacs Input

NB!! Step 2 - The menu is sometimes hidden if the window is too small.
Either maximise the window or click the < sign to expand the menu.

If Tweaks is not installed, install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl A no select all:
1, Home -> Shift End (or reverse)
2, right click or key like right click in image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4q4b.png)
-> a, Alt a, ... (to select line "select all")