# Can't use 'Ctrl' + 'A' in GNOME, after uninstalling Budgie desktop

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, desktop-environments, 20.10, budgie

I recently decided to switch back to GNOME from the Budgie environment. After purging Budgie successfully and setting up the default lock screen and splash screen, I am facing problems with some of the commonly used keyboard shortcuts. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd>) + <kbd>A</kbd> is no longer working (for selecting text in a file, search bar etc).

Any fix?
Thank you in advance.

- Gnome Version: 3.36.8
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 - LTS

Comment: May be instructive: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa

Comment: You could [reset to default](https://askubuntu.com/a/315226/349837): `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys`, or [clic on _Reset all_](https://askubuntu.com/a/963318/349837)

Comment: @PabloBianchi Tried the above two ways, not working :(

Comment: @LiamProven already tried that, no luck :(

Comment: [Try this](https://askubuntu.com/a/324880/349837), `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme`

Comment: @PabloBianchi Thanks !!. That worked !!